# SQL selecting a column, SUM and ORDER BY using three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Stocks
Id        size   qty
100       90     80
123       180    100
100       90     100
100       180    10 

Prices
Id        size   price     priceDt
100       90     100       2014-05-10 19:00:00
123       180    150       2014-05-22 19:10:19
100       180    180       2014-05-20 19:10:19
100       90     120       2014-05-22 19:10:19

Sales
Id        size   qtySold   
100       90     15
100       90     5
123       180    10
```

Now i need to retrieve LATEST price and quantitiy available (Sum(Stocks.qty) - Sum(Sales.qtySold))
on Id & size

So for Id = '100' & size = '90'
current price 
is 120

available quantity
is 160

Comment: i was trying with something like this SELECT sum(b.qtyArr), a.price
FROM prices a 
INNER JOIN stocks b
ON a.brandId = b.brandId 
WHERE a.brandId=1 
ORDER BY priceDt DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: could you outline the desired output its not clear what exactly you want.

Comment: total quantity for Id=100 & size=90 from stocks is 180 and i have sold 20 of them so existing quantity is 160,  and the LATESs price is taken from the prices table is 120 and NOT 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub query to get the latest price date, and join to prices:-

```
SELECT stocks.id, stocks.size, prices.price, SUM(stocks.qty) - sales.qtySold   
FROM stocks
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, size, MAX(priceDT) AS MaxPriceDate
    FROM prices
    GROP BY id, size
) Sub1
ON stocks.id = Sub1.id AND stocks.size = Sub1.size
INNER JOIN prices
ON Sub1.id = prices.id AND Sub1.size = prices.size AND Sub1.MaxPriceDate = prices.priceDT
INNER JOIN sales
ON stocks.id = sales.id AND stocks.size = sales.size
GROUP BY stocks.id, stocks.size
```

My concern is that sales has multiple rows for each id / size

EDIT - to cope with multiple rows on sales for an id / size using an additional subquery:-

```
SELECT stocks.id, stocks.size, prices.price, SUM(stocks.qty) - Sub2.tot_qtySold   
FROM stocks
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, size, MAX(priceDT) AS MaxPriceDate
    FROM prices
    GROUP BY id, size
) Sub1
ON stocks.id = Sub1.id AND stocks.size = Sub1.size
INNER JOIN prices
ON Sub1.id = prices.id AND Sub1.size = prices.size AND Sub1.MaxPriceDate = prices.priceDT
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, size, SUM(qtySold) AS tot_qtySold
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY id, size
) Sub2
ON stocks.id = Sub2.id AND stocks.size = Sub2.size
GROUP BY stocks.id, stocks.size
```

ON sqlfiddle:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7d37/2

EDIT - in answer to a question posted in the comment:-

The reason for this is that there are 2 matching records on the stocks table.

So for brandid 100 and size of 90 there are these 2 records from stocks:-

```
brandId size    qtyArr
(100 ,  90   ,  10),
(100 ,  90   ,  100),
```

and this one from sales:-

```
brandId size    qtySold
(100,   90, 35),
```

So MySQL will build up table initially containing a set of 2 rows. The first row will contain the first row from stocks and the only matching row from sales. The 2nd row will have the 2nd row from stocks and (again the matching row from sales).

```
brandId size    qtyArr  brandId size    qtySold
(100,   90, 10, 100,    90, 35),
(100,   90, 100,    100,    90, 35),
```

It then performs the SUM of qtySold, but the quantities are counted twice (ie, once for each match records on stocks).

To get around this will likely need a sub query to get the total qtysold for each brand / size, then join the results of that sub query against the stocks table

```
SELECT SUM(s.qtyArr), SUM(l.qtySold) 
FROM stocks s 
INNER join 
(
    SELECT brandId, size, sum(l.qtySold)
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY brandId, size
) l 
ON l.brandId = s.brandId
AND l.size = s.size
WHERE s.brandId='100' AND s.size='90';
```

Comment: Amended top cope with this

Comment: almost.. there ... but how do is retrieve for only id 100 & size 90...plz

Comment: Just add a WHERE clause of `WHERE stocks.id=100 and stocks.size=90` just before the last GROUP BY

Comment: congrts! on 10k... :)

Comment: In continuation how can i retrieve name of id column from 'Category' table....this is my updated fiddle with Category table http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/186cd6/1

Comment: You can just join on to the category table to get the brandname (and add it to the GROUP BY as well as the select). http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/186cd6/3 . However if more complex than this it should probably be done as a fresh question.

Comment: Thanks man.....thatz gr8....Could u refer me any good books to learn SQL .. PLZZZ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54275/discussion-between-x-code-and-kickstart).

Comment: Not sure of any. Ages since I bought one. With SQL there are 2 (main) areas to understand. Syntax which books and web pages can help you with, but which you can always look up when you forget (I am always checking the MySQL manual pages to see the order of parameters for functions). The 2nd is how data works as sets and how you can narrow data down by relating one set to another, which is more of a way of thinking (and quite different to how you think for normal programming). Possibly worth having a google search for "sql set theory" and having a brief read of the various pages.

Comment: Let me guess ur in DB side... DBA or something rit?

Comment: Just a normal application programmer who likes to play with SQL. And been programming too long so I get bored.

Comment: sorry to disturb could u plz look into this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ec72/2 here im not getting qtySold properly

Comment: Fixed - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ec72/6 `SELECT SUM(s.qtyArr), l.qtySold
FROM stocks s 
INNER join 
(
    SELECT brandId, size, sum(qtySold) AS qtySold
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY brandId, size
) l 
ON l.brandId = s.brandId
AND l.size = s.size
WHERE s.brandId='100' AND s.size='90';`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you require

```
SELECT b.id, sum(b.qty), sum(b.qty)-s.qtysold, max(a.price )
FROM stocks b INNER JOIN (select * from prices
                          where pricedt in(
                            select max(priceDT) as priceDt 
                          from prices
                          group by id, size))a ON (a.Id = b.Id 
and b.size=a.size)
inner join sales s on (b.id=s.id and b.size=s.size)
group by b.id, b.size
ORDER BY a.priceDt
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee892/14)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.price, (Sum(s.qty) - sa.qtySold)  
FROM prices p inner join stocks s on p.id=s.id 
             inner join sales sa on p.id=sa.id 
WHERE id=100 and size=90 
ORDER BY pricedt ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I hope this query will meet your requirement

Comment: This will have issues due to multiple matching rows on each table resulting in some of the quantities being counted multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

My stab at it:

```
   select   p.id, p.size, x.qty - y.qty as Stock, p.price
   from (
     (select *
     from prices )  p
    inner join (
            select id, Size, Max(pricedt) as  pricedt
            from prices 
            group by id, Size)q  
    on  p.pricedt   = q.pricedt  and p.id = q.id and p.size = q.size
    inner join 
            (
            select SUM(qty) as qty, size, id
            from stocks
            group by size, id   ) x 
    on p.id = x.id and p.size = x.size
    inner join 
            (
            select SUM(qtysold) as qty, size, id
            from sales
            group by size, id ) y 
    on x.id = y.id and x.size = y.size
)
```